# Alterar background e color de input password no bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Personalizei todos os campos de entrada do website passando novos valores para as classes do Bootstrap 3, ao alterar o `input[type='password']` da folha de estilo do Bootstrap 3 (folha avulta após o carregamento do css do BS3), o mesmo não altera, todos os outros inputs, os selects, textarea, sim:

```
.form-control, 
.form-control:focus, 
#contact-form input, 
#contact-form textarea, 
#contact-form select, 
form#formUpdate input, 
form#formUpdate textarea, 
form#formUpdate select, 
form#formUpdateContato input, 
form#formUpdateContato textarea, 
form#formUpdateContato select, 
form input, form textarea, 
form select, 
.header-search form input, 
.header-search form select, 
.header-search form select option, 
.listComments .listCommentsQuestion, 
textarea, 
input, 
select, 
select option, 
form password, 
password {
        background-color: #6A6969;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

Comment: @hugocsl não é autocomplete de Chrome, não se aplica a isso, pois já tratei esse problema com o Chrome no início do projeto com algumas libraries, o problema é específico. Por gentileza leia a pergunta toda antes de marcar como duplicata.

Comment: Achei que vc estava falando do fundo amarelo ou azul que o Browser coloca por padrão em campos de Password e Email... foi mal... de qq forma já deixei uma resposta ai que acho que vai resolver o problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema provavelmente é por causa disso

```
...
form password, 
password {
    background-color: #6A6969;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

O atributo `password` não exite, pelo menos não dessa forma, por isso não pegou o estilo!
 Deveria ser algo como

```
[type="password" ] {
    background-color: #6A6969;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Ai sim funcionaria

```css
.form-control, 
.form-control:focus, 
#contact-form input, 
#contact-form textarea, 
#contact-form select, 
form#formUpdate input, 
form#formUpdate textarea, 
form#formUpdate select, 
form#formUpdateContato input, 
form#formUpdateContato textarea, 
form#formUpdateContato select, 
form input, form textarea, 
form select, 
.header-search form input, 
.header-search form select, 
.header-search form select option, 
.listComments .listCommentsQuestion, 
textarea, 
input, 
select, 
select option, 
form [type="password" ] {
        background-color: #6A6969;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

```html
<input type="password" name="" id="">
```

Comment: Sim resolveu de fato. Obrigado por isso.

Comment: @EliseuB. sem problemas

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se ao colocar “!important” funciona.
Pode ser que o elemento esteja relacionado a elementos país e vc tenha que montar a árvore seguindo do pai até o elemento filho, ex:

Body>.pai>.filho>.elemento{
   CSS aqui
}

Ou

.elemento {
   CSS: css!important;
}

Comment: Nao foi. Dificilmente crio com outras dependencias. Deve ser css de plugin. Vlw

Comment: Não digo nem que sejam outras dependências, seria mais pela própria hierarquia  do css. Eu  costumo ter problemas desses dois tipos outro pode ser a posição do css no escopo, pode ser que algum css esteja sobrepondo o seu por estar posicionado abaixo do seu, e por isso é renderizado depois do seu e tem predominância. Sugiro verificar  e colocar o seu css como ultimo elemento no seu <head>